# How to create this type of button?

Tags: android

[This is the UI for login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3qz6.jpg)

How do I create this type of button please help me out new to android and practicing the UI design

[this is the login button and also similar style for other buttons also like registration submit etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo5g4.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you done anything to try replicate this?

Comment: no, I have a login screen design which i don't know how to design step by step

Comment: @Lorddirt I have included login screen UI, first of all, can you tell me is it possible to design this, and if yes then how shall I proceed?

Comment: if someone has already done it.... then why would you think it is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent almost 1 hours to design this by myself. Hopefully, this will help you.

**button_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#99ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
            <padding android:right="70dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fdffa811" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:radius="90dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

RelativeLayout

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="238dp"
        android:text="Login Now"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forward_black_24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Vector icon for TextView..

**forward_black_24dp.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#f19b06"
        android:pathData="M12,4l-1.41,1.41L16.17,11H4v2h12.17l-5.58,5.59L12,20l8,-8z"/>
</vector>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious time. and this really helped me.

Comment: Pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/________">
```

Add the iamge to your drawables and add its name in empty line above

This will add ui as shown

Comment: thank you, sir, I thought of this idea before that for every button I have to put the image right. But I was wondering if there anything I can design and reuse this type of button.

Comment: If you are using the same style for many buttons, you can use a custom button. If its only a 1 or 2 buttons, then better to follow this approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom drawable like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- use layer list to apply your background -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_here" /> <!-- your background here -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

        <!-- To have rounded corner -->
            <corners
                 android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                 android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                 android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
         </shape>
   </item>

</layer-list>
```